# Problem changin database location

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report developed with Crystal '08 and it is published on CMC.
My problem is when I changed the database to the production db, the report still asking for the development database password.
I've tried to publish the report with a diferent name, but it didn't work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you sure you switched everything over, including subreports?

Comment: Can you post the section of code where you assign the connection info to the report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I haven't seen your comment, PowerUser.
I have not seen that I had a dynamic parameter from the development db, so I solved it changig the paramenter's location.

Thanks for your help PowerUser. 
sergiogx we aften forget to see if there are any dependecy on the old database, so we should look for it carefully.

Thanks for all of you.